# Adding class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this below code that loads a tree menu:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".treeview li>ul").css('display', 'none'); // Hide all 2-level ul
    $(".Treeviewcollapsible").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("Treeviewcollapse Treeviewexpand");
        $(this).closest('li').children('ul').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

it renders a bunch of html links like

```
<a url... </a>
```

But i need it to render them with an anchor class for all levels so something like

```
<a class="menu" url.... </a>
```

Can someone please help with that?

I want to then use the below, or join the below with the top to load a partial page without reloading the rest to maintain the tree menu state

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a.menu").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefaul(); // prevent default link button redirect behaviour
  var url=$(this).attr("href");
  $('#page-content').load(url);
 });
});
```

***EDIT***

found where the html was rendering and put it in there, sorry obvious solution but new to this!

Comment: You want to add class "menu" to <a> but in your selector you are trying to select $("ul.menu a"), "ul" with class "menu".  Do you want to change the description in your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your line that looks like this:

```
$(this).closest('li').children('ul').slideToggle();
```

with a line that looks like this

```
$(this).closest('li').children('ul').addClass('menu').slideToggle();
```

This new section finds the closest `li`, goes into the `ul` that is a child element of that `li`, finds all the anchor tags( `find('a')` ), adds a class to all of those, the `end()` resets the query back to the `children('ul')`, and then performs the slideToggle

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a go.  I found when I used the bottom Jquery scrip with action links that it worked to render a partial page but it stopped the links from working to click others.  Can you see any obvious reason why?

Comment: want to give it another try? I edited the jquery so that it would add the menu class onto the UL rather than the a tags within them. I think i misread your original request.

Comment: i also noticed you have menu as a class on both your anchor tags, as well as your ul.menu in your click handler. Which is supposed to have the class added to it? The click handler will only fire if you click on a link within a ul that has a class of menu. Possibly edit your .click selector?